# Stripping down a multdimensional array and then outputting

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

so this is an odd one. I'm building a multi-email checker based on the 'Have I been pwned?' service. I have already built the function that loops through each email address, however in the output it's turned into a multidimensional array which runs really deep, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ["foo@bar.com"] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => 000webhost
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Adobe
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Patreon
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Plex
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            ["foo2@bar.com"] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => 000webhost
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I'd love to know how to strip this down so I can output it into a proper report for each email address that will list each breach according to the respective email address. I've tried a loop within a loop within a loop but that doesn't work. Like I say this array runs very deep. If somebody could help me that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you showed your desired result according with array sample.

Comment: @fushion3k Ahh yes I see well to be honest I'd just like to strip that down so it doesn't run so deep if at all possible. Like so `code` Array ( "foo@bar.com" => [0] => "Name" => "Adobe" ) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do there but if you want to get the mails and the number of breaches from the arrays, you can do it like that:

```
  $results = array(
            "foo@bar.com"=>array(
                    array("000webhost"),
                    array("Adobe"),
                    array("Patreon"),
                    array("Plex")
            ),
            "foo2@bar.com"=>array(
                    array("000webhost2")
            )
);


  foreach ($results as $mail=>$value) {
        echo "Mail: ".$mail." Breaches: ".count($value)."<br>";
  }
```

**Result:**

```
Mail: foo@bar.com Breaches: 4
Mail: foo2@bar.com Breaches: 1
```

Comment: I can't seem to strip the array down. The problem is the original return value is already in the format of a JSON array. I wish that I could provide a better way of putting this all. I don't know how to strip it all down so it fits into a neat array like the one you've put above.

Comment: This URL is one used as an example by Troy Hunt himself to show how it works - https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/troyhunt@hotmail.com?truncateResponse=true you will see the JSON output

Comment: I hope I understand you right...
Let's say we have this JSON as presented in this url:
`$json = '[{"Name":"000webhost"},{"Name":"Adobe"},{"Name":"Patreon"},{"Name":"Plex"}]';`. 
Now if you will run `json_decode($json, true);` you will get a nice array like this: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => 000webhost
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Adobe
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Patreon
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Plex
        )

)`

And then continue from my code above:)

Comment: Check my edited post now and tell me if that's what you've meant.

Comment: I just deleted the last comment. I've managed to work out how to do it. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Just one last thing actually, when getting the count, how would I get the total count for the breaches. I've tried $count = count($value); but that just gave me 1 when echoing it out. Say I wanted to do a header <h2><?php echo ($count); ?> Sites Breached</h2> How could I do that? Obviously the total would be 5 breaches.